# ng-click not working on dynamic hyperlink

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

I have a empty table to start, A form with a add button is used to populate rows in table one by one.
Last column in the table is delete and i have populated a hyperlink with `ng-click` attribute but its not getting fired... i tried `onclick` function it works.

HTML :

```
<tr ng-repeat="entity in entities">
    <td>{{ $index + 1 }}</td>
    <td>{{ entity.entityType }}</td>
    <td>{{ entity.orgType }}</td>
    <td>{{ entity.entityId }}</td>
    <td>{{ entity.name }}</td>
    <td>{{ entity.addressLine1 }}</td>
    <td>{{ entity.city }}</td>
    <td>{{ entity.state }}</td>
    <td>{{ entity.zip }}</td>
    <td ng-bind-html="entity.edit"></td>
    <td ng-bind-html="entity.remove"></td>
</tr>
```

Javascript this is the click event that is called to add a row in table :

```
 $scope.entities = [];

 $scope.addEntity = function() {
     console.log($scope.entity);
     $scope.entity.$index = $scope.entities.length;
     var $el = "<a ng-click='deleteEntity(" + $scope.entity.$index + ")'>Delete</a>";
     $scope.entity.edit = $sce.trustAsHtml("<a ng-click='editEntity(" + $scope.entity.$index + ")'>Edit</a>");
     $scope.entity.remove = $sce.trustAsHtml($el);
     $scope.entities.push($scope.entity);
     $scope.reset();
     $compile($el)($scope);
 }
```

HTML is created properly, with `deleteEntity` function have index values.

Comment: Did you try to compile it before insert ? $compile

Comment: I tried that also but it wasn't working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this directly:

```
<tr ng-repeat="entity in entities track by $index">
    <td>{{ $index + 1 }}</td>
    <td>{{ entity.entityType }}</td>
    <td>{{ entity.orgType }}</td>
    <td>{{ entity.entityId }}</td>
    <td>{{ entity.name }}</td>
    <td>{{ entity.addressLine1 }}</td>
    <td>{{ entity.city }}</td>
    <td>{{ entity.state }}</td>
    <td>{{ entity.zip }}</td>
    <td><a ng-click='editEntity($index)'>Edit</a></td>
    <td><a ng-click='deleteEntity($index)'>Delete</a></td>
</tr>
```

I think this will solve your problem.

Comment: it works.. i removed entity.edit and entity.remove i was passing from javascript.